# Algorithm to get best combination

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, go

I have items with ID `1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`. Now I have data like following.
There is an offerId for each row. `Array of Ids` consist of combination of the `ID` in an array. `Discount` is the value for that `offerId`

```
offerId : Array of Ids     : Discount
o1      : [1]              : 45
o2      : [1 3 4]          : 100
o3      : [3 5]            : 55
o4      : [5]              : 40
o5      : [6]              : 30
o6      : [6 7]            : 20
```

Now I have to select all the offerIds which give me best combination of Ids i.e. maximum total discount.

For example in above case : possible results can be:

[o2, o4, o5] maximum discount is `170(100 + 40 + 30)`.

Note. the result offerId should be such that Ids don't repeat. Example for `o2,o4,o6` ids are [1,3,4], [5], [6] all are distinct.

Other combination can be :
`o1, o3, 06` for which ids are [1], [3,5], [6,7] However the total is 120(45+55+20) which is less then `170` as in previous case.

I need an algorithm/code which will help me to identify `combination of offerIds` which will give `maximum discount` , considering that each offer should contain distinct `Ids`.

**NOTE** I am writing my code in `go` language. But solutions/Logic in any language will be helpful.

**NOTE :** I hope I am able to explain my requirement properly. please comment if any extra information is required. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question. Please don't downvote.

Comment: This looks no easier than [exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) but with weights, so I'd say a polynomial solution is unlikely.

Comment: In this problem, if there are only few IDs (say, at most 20), I'd go with a dynamic programming solution: f (`s`: subset of IDs) = maximum possible discount for any set of offers giving exactly subset `s`.

Comment: I have edited my question. Sometimes best combination will not be `exact cover ` of a set. (note: I have changed value of o5 to 30)

Comment: So, you have to check all possible subsets, not just the whole set. The algorithm complexity remains the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124645/discussion-between-jagrati-and-gassa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a dynamic programming solution which, for every possible subset of IDs, finds the combination of offers for which the discount is maximum possible.
This will be pseudocode.

Let our offers be structures with fields `offerNumber`, `setOfItems` and `discount`.
For the purposes of implementation, we first renumerate the possible items by integers from zero to number of different possible items (say `k`) minus one.
After that, we can represent `setOfItems` by a binary number of length `k`.
For example, if `k` = 6 and `setOfItems` = 101110<sub>2</sub>, this set includes items 5, 3, 2 and 1 and excludes items 4 and 0, since bits 5, 3, 2 and 1 are ones and bits 4 and 0 are zeroes.

Now let `f[s]` be the best discount we can get using exactly set `s` of items.
Here, `s` can be any integer between 0 and 2<sup>k</sup> - 1, representing one of the 2<sup>k</sup> possible subsets.
Furthermore, let `p[s]` be the list of offers which together allow us to get discount `f[s]` for the set of items `s`.
The algorithm goes as follows.

```
initialize f[0] to zero, p[0] to empty list
initialize f[>0] to minus infinity
initialize bestF to 0, bestP to empty list
for each s from 0 to 2^k - 1:
    for each o in offers:
        if s & o.setOfItems == o.setOfItems:  // o.setOfItems is a subset of s
            if f[s] < f[s - o.setOfItems] + o.discount:  // minus is set subtraction
                f[s] = f[s - o.setOfItems] + o.discount
                p[s] = p[s - o.setOfItems] append o.offerNumber
                if bestF < f[s]:
                    bestF = f[s]
                    bestP = p[s]
```

After that, `bestF` is the best possible discount, and `bestP` is the list of offers which get us that discount.

The complexity is O (|offers| * 2<sup>k</sup>) where `k` is the total number of items.

Here is another implementation which is asymptotically the same, but might be faster in practice when most subsets are unreachable.
It is "forward" instead of "backward" dynamic programming.

```
initialize f[0] to zero, p[0] to empty list
initialize f[>0] to -1
initialize bestF to 0, bestP to empty list
for each s from 0 to 2^k - 1:
    if f[s] >= 0:  // only for reachable s
        if bestF < f[s]:
            bestF = f[s]
            bestP = p[s]
        for each o in offers:
            if s & o.setOfItems == 0:  // s and o.setOfItems don't intersect
                if f[s + o.setOfItems] < f[s] + o.discount:  // plus is set addition
                    f[s + o.setOfItems] = f[s] + o.discount
                    p[s + o.setOfItems] = p[s] append o.offerNumber
```

Comment: Is there any efficient algorithm to represent `setOfItems by a binary number of length k`

Comment: @Jagrati Sure. First, assign consecutive integers to all items, starting from zero. After that, each setOfItems is just a sum of 2^i for all indices i present in the set. For example, for set {0, 3, 4}, the binary representation is 2^0 + 2^3 + 2^4 = 11001 in binary.

Comment: I have one more doubt. Will this support cases where for a particular set there are two entries with different offerNumber and Discount?

Comment: Sure, the `for each o in offer` loop goes through all you give it.

Comment: I am really new to this. can you please tell me how will I do this : `s & o.setOfItems == 0` and `s + o.setOfItems` where `s` is a number from 0 to 2^k -1 and `o.setOfItems` is also a number from `0 to 2^k -1` . Sorry for bothering you so much !!

Comment: @Jagrati & is [bitwise and](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105938/golang-bitwise-operations-as-well-as-general-byte-manipulation), and + is just a regular + which adds together two integers.

Comment: I have another problem which is similar to this question. Please help if you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847065/algorithm-to-find-best-combination-of-offers-depending-on-constraints