# Algorithm to find best combination of offers depending on constraints

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I have items with ID and respective quantity in an array of map with `id` as first element and its `quantity` as second element .

`[100 : 1, 300 : 2, 400:2, 600 : 2, 700 : 1]`. I have input data :

```
 1 quantity of `100`
 2 quantity of `300`
 2 quantity of `400`
 2 quantity of `600`
 1 quantity of `700`
```

Now I have stored data like below. There is an offerId for each row. `map of Id and quantity` consist of combination of the `ID` and `respective quantity` for which the offer can be applied. `Discount` is the value for that `offerId`

```
offerId | map of Id and quantity           | Discount
o1      | [100 : 2]                        | 45
o2      | [100 : 1, 300 : 2, 400 : 2]      | 100
o3      | [300 : 1]                        | 55
o4      | [600 : 1]                        | 30
o5      | [600 : 1, 700 : 1]               | 20
```

Now I have to select all the offerIds which give me best combination of Ids i.e. maximum total discount, with quantity

For example in above case : possible results can be:

P = [o1, o3, o4, 05] maximum discount is `150(45 + 55 + 30 + 20)`. (Note : P should have distinct offer ids, i.e. same offer cannot be applied twice)

```
o1 applied on 2 quantity of `100`
o3 applied on 1 quantity of `300`
o4 applied on 1 quantity of `600`
o5 applied on 1 quantity of `600` and 1 quantity of `700`
```

`o4` applied on 1 quantity of 600. Remining quantity of `600` after o4 is applied is `1` (as in the input we are passing 2 quantities of `600`). Hence o5 can also be applies.

I need an algorithm/code which will help me to identify `combination of offerIds` which will give `maximum discount` , considering that each id has a quantity with it`.

**NOTE** I had earlier asked the similar question without considering the quantity here : [Algorithm to get best combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791544/algorithm-to-get-best-combination/39792597?noredirect=1#comment66971154_39792597) . Hope this will help to find the solution to this problem

**NOTE :** I hope I am able to explain my requirement properly. please comment if any extra information is required. Thanks.

Comment: You should look for a greedy algorithm. I think that'll work.

Comment: I have asked a question similar to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791544/algorithm-to-get-best-combination/39792597?noredirect=1#comment66971154_39792597               I am able to use this solution to get best offers but without considering quantity. I think that this solution can be modified to incorporate by needs. But I don't know how?

Comment: Sort the Discounts. As greedy approach, start picking the items in descending order. For a particular discount pick the item with min. quantity, as u want to maximize discount by keeping the quantity min.
Keep a counter for number of items chosen till now, to make sure that chosen items is less than maxItems

Hope it helps.